# fatal: unable to access ' ': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21058 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Tags: git, github, push, publish

I installed and have been using GitHub Desktop, which was working normally until a few days ago. However, now I am unable to push or publish my files to GitHub using GitHub Desktop. I don't remember what I did that could have caused this issue. When I try to push or publish, I receive an error message:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/.../.../'': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21058ms: Couldn't connect to server.

I am hoping for some assistance in resolving this error, as it is taking me a long time to fix it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the VPN, you can try `git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:7890`(7890 is the port of your vpn) and `git config --global https.proxy https://127.0.0.1:7890`.
If not you can try `git config --global unset http.proxy` and `git config --global unset https.proxy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this problem solved automatically and I don't understand why. Perhaps there is a problem with my home's internet because when I connect using another internet the problem is resolved